# Blacklisting JWT tokens

Tags: laravel, token, jwt, laravel-5

For my API i'm using this package tymondesigns/jwt-auth with Laravel.
Security is very important! Tokens will be blacklisted after every request with a new token in the response. While doing some tests using both middlewares jwt.auth and jwt.refresh on the same route I get mixed results. Sometimes it works OK, sometimes I get a 401 unauthorized and have to login again.
I'm using the jtw.auth middleware so I can make use of Auth::user() in my app.

```
$api->group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function ($api)
{
    // Protected routes here
});
```

Does someone have a working example for this?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is an appropriate use case for JWT tokens. It could conceivably lead to a denial of service attack by flooding the service with requests, which will either use a lot of storage to blacklist all those tokens, or it will cause the blacklist to stop working by exhausting its allocated capacity.

Comment: Also, it sounds like your system is working as designed/intended which is why you are getting 401 errors.